# Imagens aleatórias background com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Eu estou usando AngularJS com Ionic para fazer um aplicativo. Em determinada tela, eu preciso exibir uma imagem aleatória. Eu procurei muito aqui e na internet uma maneira de fazer isso, mas só consegui com JS normal, sem estar em Angular e tenho algumas dúvidas de como "transformar" para usar no Angular.

```
var backgrounds = ['',
               'bg3.jpg',
               'bg1.jpg',
               'bg1013.jpg',
               'bg123.gif',
               'bg553.jpg',
               'bg663.png',
               'bgdaas3.jpg',
               'bgdw3.jpg',
               'bgdd3.jpg',
               'dasd.png'
              ];

$('#elementID').css('background','url('+backgrounds[Math.random()*10]+')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o atributo ng-style do Angular para aplicar diretamente, como por exemplo assim:

```
<div ng-style="exemplo"></div>
```

E depois no controlador utilizas assim:

```
$scope.exemplo = {'background' :'url('+backgrounds[Math.random()*10]+')'}
```

Answer (score -1):

É possível com [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), que delega um subconjunto incorporado de Angular do jQuery, chamado de *jQuery lite* ou *jqLite*.

```
angular.element('#elementID').css('background','url('+backgrounds[Math.random()*10]+')');
```

Comment: Ohh meu deus! Downvote anônimo! :)

Comment: O downvote não foi meu, porém posso deduzir que a razão tenha sido porque a sua resposta foi em jQuery, enquanto que o OP claramente especificou AngularJS.